# Como fazer credenciamento em PHP e MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, mobile

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema para eventos que será composto por um sistema web e um aplicativo mobile. Um dos pontos principais será o credenciamento (check-in e check-out) dos usuários nas palestras. Após a realização de um cadastro no site e inscrição para o evento, na chegada deste usuário ao local da palestra pretendo confirmar a presença dele na palestra de alguma forma. Preciso de alguma ideia de como fazer isso. Gerar um codigo de barras para cada evento e fazer a leitura do mesmo no crachá do usuário quando o mesmo chegar ao evento? Usar QRCode e o celular do usuário? Cada evento ter um 'código' de identificação? Então como evitar que usuários que não foram à palestra não tenham a presença confirmada por outras pessoas? Sugestões por favor.

Comment: Você pode fazer uma leitura do QRCode do cracha de identificação na portaria.

Comment: Eu apostaria num QRcode. Na palestra pode ter um QRcode e o utilizador quando chega lê o QRCode com o aplicativo. Esse QRcode reencaminha para uma URL que valida a entrada no evento. Isto é um exemplo entre muitos outros que pode fazer